# Getting C# listview to show thumbnails only when needed

Tags: c#, listview, thumbnails

I wanted to make the listview show thumbnails only when the items are visible on the screen.
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: what i mean is when you have a listview that has like about 1000 images to thumb, the thumbing starts at the first index up to the last and then you feel like viewing the last item/last index, then that means you have to wait for the other items to thumb first before you can actually see the thumb of the last item, so if there is a way to thumb only the items that you are currently viewing then you don't have to wait for the other 999 items...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by using a `ListView` in virtual mode, and then adding your generated thumbnails to the `LargeImageList` during the `RetrieveVirtualItem` event (if they are not already there).

If you wanted most of the work done for you, you could use a `FastObjectListView` from the [ObjectListView project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/objectlistview.aspx) (an open source wrapper around .NET WinForms ListView) and then follow [this recipe on how to use images loaded from a database](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/recipes.html#on-the-rows-of-my-objectlistview-i-want-to-show-images-that-come-from-a-database-how-do-i-do-that). Your images, of course, would be thumbnails created from the source rather than images from a database but the logic is the same.

Answer (score 5):

See an excellent implementation of what your after [on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/imagelistview.aspx)

Comment: that link on codeproject was an overkill, It is fine with me to have a slow generation of thumb my concern is only to find a way to thumb only the items that i'm currently viewing like how vista explorer do which only thumbs the item that currently is visible. But anyway thanks for the link i'll try to study the source code for now.